# Button is now at the TOP after setting setEmptyView

Tags: android, empty-list

After setting the `setEmptyView`, the button which was formerly at the bottom now goes up to the top of layout. Please help me figure out why. Here's my code:

**activity_list.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <ListView
          android:id="@+id/listview_snyc"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sync" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_list_empty.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/empty" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code :**

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_snyc);
list.setAdapter(new MasterFileMenuAdapter(this,data));

View emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_list_empty, null);
addContentView(emptyView, list.getLayoutParams());
list.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

**Whenever the `ListView` is empty I got this result:**

[image]

The **Refresh Button** should be in the **bottom** not on the **top**.

**Any idea?**

Comment: try change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"` in your `ListView`

Comment: @PhanVănLinh, I tried it but I cant see the empty image anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelativeLayout` in the `activity_list.xml` as well and put

```
alignParentBottom="true"
```

in the `Button` tag

Comment: You might want to put 'alignParentTop="true"' in the ListView, and 'alignAbove="buttonID"' as well

Answer (score 0):

Move your button to your empty view and align it to bottom:
**activity_list.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
      android:id="@+id/listview_snyc"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>



</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_list_empty.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/empty" />

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Sync" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The button should not be in activity_list_empty. There is a specific reason why I place that button in there.